# what is the difference between .last() and :last?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can someone explain the difference between .last() and :last ? I can't seem to find a definitive explanation.

Why Exactly does this `$('td.cellsOfSpecificClass:last', '.table tr')` return the last td in each tr instead of the last td in the whole table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`.last()`](http://api.jquery.com/last/) is a function which returns the last element of the given (existing) collection of elements. The [`:last`](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/) is a selector which is to be used in `$('...')` which immediately returns the last element instead of a whole collection. Which one to use depends on what you've as far and what you need.

---

**Update**: to clarify the last phrase a bit more:

If you *already* have a collection of elements in a variable **at the moment** you need the last element, then use `.last()`. If you don't already have it and you just need *only* the last element, then use `:last`. If you actually need *both* in the remnant of the code, then grab all elements *and* use `.last()`.

Comment: What did you mean to say in your last sentence?

Answer (score 2):

This is more to elaborate on BalusC answer in case of mis-understanding, so please up-vote his, ya?

the 'given array' is an array of jQuery elements.

```
$('.willReturnManyObjects').last()
```

will give you a *jQuery* object that's the last element found with that class name / selector.

This is the same as calling `.eq(-1);`

:last is to get the last item in the selector, but could be used to get many elements:

```
$('input:last, .extraDiv');
```

this would give you the LAST input *and* any .extraDiv elements.

Cool, eh?

edit: looks like BalusC edited his answer to be a bit more understandable while i was typing this :p

Comment: +1 for honesty and being honorable with regard to whose answer was first and/or more succinct. (Don't worry, I gave +1 to the other one too!) :-)

Comment: why would $('input:last, .extraDiv');  select the last input AND .extraDiv? isn't .extraDiv the context of the query for input?

Comment: no, because the comma is _inside_ the apostrophes - jquery is getting only one argument, the string literal with the selectors. Had the comma been outside, such as `$('input:last, .extraDiv', $contextElement);` then it would search by context..